# Identificador de 4 números en php

Tags: php, html, archivo

Tengo un formulario hecho en html, cuando lo envían se le asigna un folio. Inicialmente el folio se asignaba aleatoriamente pero ahora **necesito que comience asignar folios a partir de 0001**, (0002, 0003) y también validar que el correo ya fue registrado. Estos datos se guardan en un archivo. Adjunto una parte del código que tengo:

```
                  if(isset($_POST["titulo"]) && !empty($_POST["titulo"]) &&
                  isset($_POST["fecha"]) && !empty($_POST["fecha"])){
                   $aleatorio = rand(1, 30000);
                    $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
                    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

                   //Creación de archivo y escritura:
                    $file = "datos.txt";
                    $datos = fopen($file, "a+");
                    fwrite($datos, "Folio: " . $aleatorio . ",");
                    fwrite($datos, " Titulo: " . $titulo . " |");
                    fwrite($datos, " Fecha: " . $fecha . " |");
                     fclose($datos);
}
```

Podrían decirme alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Hola un gusto en saludarte

Yo para hacer algo parecido utilice cree función asi:

```html
    function _ceros($s){
        //inicio
        if(strlen($s) <= 1)
            $s = "00000" . $s;
        else if(strlen($s) <= 2)
            $s = "0000" . $s;
        else if( strlen($s) <= 3)
            $s = "000". $s;
        else if(strlen($s) <= 4)
            $s = "00" . $s;  
        else if(strlen($s) <= 5)
            $s = "0" . $s; 
    
        return $s;
       //fin 
    }
```

le pasas el numero que deseas colocarle los 0 y ya te devuelve el resultado que necesitas

ejemplo:

echo _ceros('10');
te devuelve: 000010

ya queda a tu gusto personalizarlo. quizás hay mejores maneras pero a mi me sirve.

El correo si te queda realizar una consulta a la BD y retornar un msj de que esta en uso o si esta disponible permitirle guardar.

Esperando te ayude feliz día!